# what could this generic class declaration could mean?

Tags: java, generics, generic-programming

I know this isn't a good question to ask and I might get cursed to ask it but I cannot find any place to get help on this question

Below is a Generic class that appeared in my interview question (which I have already failed).  The question was to tell what this Class declaration is doing and in what circumstances this could be used for ?

I have very limited understanding of Generic programming but I understand that 'T' is Type and 'extends' here means that the Type should have inherited 'SimpleGenericClass' but I do not understand the '?' at the end and in what circumstances this Class could be potentially used for

```
public abstract class SimpleGenericClass<T extends SimpleGenericClass<?>> {

}
```

Comment: Are they both `Simple` or `Sample`, or are they supposed to be different classes?

Comment: Sorry about that, its SimpleGenericClass - I have updated it.. Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, because the class `SimpleGenericClass` is *abstract*, it is meant to be subclassed.

Second, it is a *generic* class which means that inside the class somewhere you will almost assuredly be using the generic parameter `T` as the type of a field.

```
public abstract class SimpleGenericClass<T...> {
    T x;
}
```

Now the **first** interesting thing here is that `T` is *bounded*.  Because it is declared as `T extends SimpleGenericClass<?>` it can only be `SimpleGenericClass<?>` or some subclass of `SimpleGenericClass<?>`.  You also asked about thr `?`.  That's known as a wildcard and there is a pretty good explanation of it at [the Java Tutorial on Wildcards](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/extra/generics/wildcards.html).  In your case we would say this is a "SimpleGenericClass of unknown."  It is needed in Java because `SimpleGenericClass<Object>` is NOT the superclass of `SimpleGenericClass<String>`, for example.

The **second** interesting thing though is that since `T` is a `SimpleGenericClass` of some sort, your class is more than likely defining  *recursive structures*.  What comes to my mind are trees (think of expression trees) where `SimpleGenericClass` is the (abstract) node type, designed to be subclassed with all kinds of specialized node types.

**UPDATE** [This SO question on self-bounded generics](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3333590/generic-tree-self-bounded-generics) might be helpful to you.

**UPDATE 2**

I went ahead and put together some code that illustrates how this can be used.  The app doesn't do anything but it does compile and it shows you how the generic bounds can supply some possibly-meaningful constraints.

```
public abstract class Node<T extends Node<?>> {
    public abstract T[] getChildren();
}

class NumberNode extends Node {
    int data;
    public Node[] getChildren() {return new Node[]{};}
}

class IdentifierNode extends Node {
    int data;
    public Node[] getChildren() {return new Node[]{};}
}

class PlusNode extends Node {
    NumberNode left;
    NumberNode right;
    public NumberNode[] getChildren() {return new NumberNode[]{};}
}
```

The nice thing here is that `NumberNode[]` is a valid return type for `PlusNode.getChildren`!  Does that matter in practice?  No idea, but it is pretty cool. :)

It's not the greatest example, but the question was rather open ended ("what might such a thing be used for?").  There are other ways to define trees, of course.

Answer (score 0):

This really only means that you allow the user of class SimpleGenericClass to parametrize instances of the class with the type T. However, T cannot be any type, but must be a subtype of SampleGenericClass (or SampleGenericClass itself).

In the remainder of the code of class SimpleGenericClass you may use type T in method signatures.

Let's assume for a second that SimpleGenericClass is not abstract. When using it, you could then write:

```
new SimpleGenericClass<SampleGenericClass<String>>();
```

I.e. you parametrize SimpleGenericClass with SampleGenericClass and SampleGenericClass with String.

Comment: Sorry hendrik, it wasn't a SampleGenericClass a second time rather its only SimpleGenericClass... I have updated the question.. can you have a look again

Answer (score 0):

By definition it says that the `SimpleGenericClass` can work on a type `<T>` which is subclass of  SimpleGenericClass.

So I assume there will be some operations which will work on `<T>`.

Now to see why one would define a template like this - (not much I can think of , really ) may be a scenario where the `SimpleGenericClass` is an abstract class (**just realized it is as per OP :P**) and expects that it can work on any concrete classes ?

Guys what do you think ?

Answer (score 0):

This basically sais: in this class you have a Type placeholder called T, and a restriction on that placeholder, it must be of type SimpleGenericClass or something that extends it. Once you obey that rule you can create instances of your class and give  an actual type to T, that later on can be used in methods of that class, something like this:

```
public class C <T extends Number>{

    public void doSomething(T t) {

    }

    public static void main(String... args) {
        //works:
        C<Number> c = new C<Number>();
        c.doSomething(new Number() {
            //Aonimous implementation of number

        });

        //won't work
        //C<Object> c = new C<Object>();

        C<Integer> c2 = new C<Integer>();       
        c2.doSomething(new Integer(1));
        //won't work
        //c2.doSomething(new Number() {

            //Aonimous implementation of number
        //});
    }
}
```

The  `SimpleGenericClass<?>` is pretty redundant at this point. If another generic type is needed on this class, you can have more than one (`SimpleGenericClass<T extends SimpleGenericClass, T2 extends Whatever>`)

Answer (score 0):

I guess you have got the question in this form (`T` instead of `?`):

```
public abstract class SimpleGenericClass<T extends SimpleGenericClass<T>>
```

Take a look at this code:

```
abstract class Foo<SubClassOfFoo extends Foo<SubClassOfFoo>>
{
    /** subclasses are forced to return themselves from this method */
    public abstract SubClassOfFoo subclassAwareDeepCopy();
}

class Bar extends Foo<Bar> {
    public Bar subclassAwareDeepCopy() {
        Bar b = new Bar();
        // ...
        return b;
    }
}

Bar b = new Bar();
Foo<Bar> f = b;
Bar b2 = b.subclassAwareDeepCopy();
Bar b3 = f.subclassAwareDeepCopy(); // no need to cast, return type is Bar
```

The trick going on with `Foo<SubClassOfFoo extends Foo<SubClassOfFoo>>` is:

- Any subclass of `Foo` must supply a type argument to `Foo`.
- That type    argument must actually be a subclass of `Foo`.
- Subclasses    of `Foo` (like    `Bar`) follow the idiom that the type
  argument they    supply to `Foo` is    themselves.
- Foo has a method that returns `SubClassOfFoo`. Combined
  with the above idiom, this allows Foo to formulate a contract that
  says “any subclass of me must implement `subclassAwareDeepCopy()` and
  they must declare that it returns that actual subclass“.

To say that another way: this idiom allows a superclass (such as an Abstract Factory) to define methods whose argument types and return types are in terms of the subclass type, not the superclass type.

The trick is done for example in `Enum` JDK class:

```
public abstract class Enum<E extends Enum<E>>
```

Refer [here](http://madbean.com/2004/mb2004-3/) for more details.